# Bayesian matrix factorization

Tags: bayesian, recommender-system, stan

I am working with Bayesian matrix factorization using the MovieLens database.
Data consist of a matrix $n \times d$ of $n=943$ users and $d=1682$ movies where users assign a rate (1-5) to movies.
Clearly this results in a very sparse matrix since I have only 100000 observations out of 943*1682 possible entries.

I define the likelihood as $P(X|W, Z, \beta) = \prod_{(i,j) \in Obs} \mathcal{N}(X_{ij}|Z_iW_j^t, \beta^{-1})$ 
where $Z = n \times k$ matrix and $W=d \times k$ with $k$ = number of features, $Obs$ are the observed entries in the original matrix $X$.

I want to compute the posterior probability $P(Z, W,\beta|X)$.

I implemented this in Stan (using basic prior just to see if everything works):

```
data {
    int<lower=0> n_users;                       // Number of users (943)
    int<lower=0> n_movies;                      // Number of movies (1682)
    int<lower=0> n_features;                    // Number of features 
    int<lower=1> n_entries;                     // Number of entries in matrix 

    matrix[n_users, n_movies] rating; 


}
parameters {
    matrix[n_features, n_movies] W;         
    matrix[n_users, n_features] Z;
}

model {
    to_vector(rating) ~ normal(to_vector(Z*W), 1.0); // Likelihood 

    // Priors
    to_vector(W) ~ normal(0,1);
    to_vector(Z) ~ normal(0,1);
}
```

The problem is that it takes a huge amount of time to compute the posterior probability, is there a way to speed up the computation?
I know that I should somehow include only the observations but I can't really figure out how to do it

Comment: You are exploring a very big parameter space.  Stan is expected to be slow in this case because it has to perform symplectic integration for all the parameters **and** their momentum, effectively doubling the parameter space.  I'm also confident there exist better priors for W and Z than just placing a normal on each of the elements.  I'm not sure what that prior is, but perhaps someone has written about it.

Comment: You can speed things up a bit by defining `vector[n_users * n_movies] rating_vec = to_vector(rating);` in the transformed data block after the model block and then referring to `rating_vec` in the normal likelihood. There is no need to reshape a constant matrix to a vector every time the log-kernel function gets evaluated (which will be millions of times).

Answer (score 1):

What I understand, you are building a Bayesian version of the [matrix factorization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444283/recommendation-system/444289#444289) model described in [Matrix Factorization Techniques for Recommender Systems](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-[Netflix].pdf) by Koren, Bell and Volinsky. The original paper described how the model can be estimated using either stochastic gradient descent, where you iterate over the *observed* training samples and for each rating $r_{iu}$ by user $u$ and item $i$ we calculate the error

$$
e_{iu} = r_{iu} - q_i^Tp_u
$$

and update the parameters

$$
q_i \leftarrow q_i + \gamma (e_{ui} p_u-\lambda q_i) \\
p_u \leftarrow p_u + \gamma (e_{ui} q_i-\lambda p_u)
$$

I'm mentioning this, because I'm not sure if your code is correct. What are the ratings stored in `rating` matrix? It should be a $n \times k$ matrix, where $n$ is the number of users and $k$ items, where some of the ratings are missing (otherwise nothing to predict). I would expect to see rather something like a for loop:

```
for (j in 1:m) {
   rating[j] ~ normal(W[u[j], :] * Z[i[j], :], 1);
}
```

where `rating`, `u`, and `i` are vectors of length `m`, `rating` stores the ratings (non-missing!), while `user` and `item` stores the $u$ and $i$ indexes. By the way, this was [mentioned by one of the core Stan developers, Bob Carpenter on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258507/3986320).

Finally, as mentioned in the comment, you have a lot of parameters and a lot of observed values, so it probably can be quite slow.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the 'rating' matrix is n x k matrix with 100000 non-zeros elements, most of the elements are missing because not every user ranked every movie.
I was not sure the code I wrote was correct neither.
However, both `W[u[j]]` and  `Z[i[j]]` are selecting the rows, but shouldn't I need the columns of Z?
Like this `W[u[j],:] * Z[:,i[j]]`